# Which one is the correct molecule of the given properties of IR Spectroscopy?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy

1. $\ce{CH3CH=CHCO2CH3}$
2. $\ce{CH3COOCH=CHCH3}$

$\pu{2950 cm-1}, \ \pu{2870 cm-1}, \ \pu{1740 cm-1}$ are the observed peaks.

No peaks observed $\pu{1700-1500 cm-1}$.

The formula of the molecule is $\ce{C5H8O2}$.

**My pre-answer** is the first option. Because $\pu{1500-1700 cm-1}$ includes unsaturated carbons.

Comment: Does not correspond to the literature spectrum for 1  https://www.chemicalbook.com/SpectrumEN_623-43-8_IR1.htm

Comment: So, the first one is wrong. And, the answer is 2. Nothing else?@Waylander

Comment: I'm not a fan of IR as a diagnostic for structural determination, and have not used it much for the last 30 years. NMR is much stronger.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My professor is awaiting replies from me.@Waylander

Comment: 1740 is a bit low for the carbonyl of a vinyl ester according to my old copy of Williams & Fleming but it could be that signal